# Javascript: Element wont appear even its visibility is changed to visible in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am kind of struggling with the following problem:

(1) Description:

I have been trying to make my own GDPR pop-up window (for those of you who do not deal with EU and do not need to know this stuff, its that annoying popup blocking half of your screen and saying: "*This site is using cookies....*").

The pop-up is a simple div.

The ID of this div is set to "GDPRcontainer" in the following way:

```
<div class="card text-center static-bottom" id="GDPRcontainer">
```

The visibility of this  is by default set to "hidden" in my css in the following way:

```
#GDPRcontainer 
{
  ...
  visibility: hidden!important;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the div appears if a specific cookie is not set (the cookie is set when the user confirms or dismisses the popup).

(2) What I tried

I am trying to achieve this by calling a function with the onLoad event from the body tag as follows:

```
onLoad="checkGDPR('GDPR=noted')"
```

This calls the checkGDPR function, that checks whether the cookie is set, and if it determines that the cookie is not set, it calls the function ukazovak('GDPRcontainer') that is supposed to change the visibility of the div to "visible":

```
function ukazovak(elid)
{
document.getElementById(elid).style.visibility = 'visible';


}
```

No matter how I try the div does not appear. In order to debug, I added

```
window.alert(document.getElementById('GDPRcontainer').style.visibility);
```

into the ukazovak() function to check, whether the visibility has been changed. The alert says "visible", but the div does not appear (does not become visible).

I am using Bootstrap, so it it possible that this is come kind of css preference clash, but I do not want to be suggestive :).

Many thanks in advance for reading all this.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: `!important` overwrites any other declaration. And it is generally bad practice to use it in almost all cases. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception

Comment: "*annoying popup blocking half of your screen*" – That is purely a design choice to nag users. GDPR does not have anything to do with those dark-pattern stylings at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I totally agree, but from what I understand, If you are using Bootstrap, this is often the most sensible way to go. Bootstrap themselves sometimes use !important to resolve css clashes.

Comment: Why are you using visibility instead of display?

Comment: Shoud using visibility also be a viable solution? And potentially a more correct one, as per W3schools: (A) The visibility property specifies whether or not an element is visible. (B) The display property specifies if/how an element is displayed. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp